# fastest way to load image thumbnails into grid

Tags: java, android, performance

I'm trying to show a gridview with all the users images in it.

but loading the images from the android MediaStore.

I have to do a request and then loop over the images from the result to get every single thumbnail, this results in a huge lag!

how would I compress these calls into a single request or how would I save more time on this?

```
 String[] projection = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION
    };

    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC, " +
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED + " DESC";

    ContentResolver cr = ctx.getContentResolver();
    final Cursor cursorImages = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            sortOrder);

    ArrayList<ImageDataHolder> images = new ArrayList<ImageDataHolder>(cursorImages.getCount());

    if (cursorImages.moveToFirst()) {
        final int dataColumn = cursorImages.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        final int idColumn = cursorImages.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);

        do {

            final Long imageID = cursorImages.getLong(idColumn);
            final String imagePath = cursorImages.getString(dataColumn);
            final int imageOrientation = cursorImages.getInt(dataColumn);

            // create new cursor to get thumbnail path
            final Cursor cursorThumb = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.queryMiniThumbnail(ctx.getContentResolver(), imageID,
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);

            String thumbPath = "";
            if (cursorThumb != null) {
                if (cursorThumb.getCount() > 0) {
                    cursorThumb.moveToFirst();
                    thumbPath = cursorThumb.getString(cursorThumb.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA));
                }
                cursorThumb.close(); // cleanup crew, isle 7
            }

            // create new ImageDataHolder and add to images ArrayList
            // only if we have a thumbnail to show
            if (thumbPath != "")
                images.add(new ImageDataHolder(imagePath, thumbPath, imageID, imageOrientation));

        } while (cursorImages.moveToNext());
    }

    cursorImages.close();

    return images;
```